# Permission Denied when executing container on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions, dockerfile, shebang

When executing my Docker container I continue to get permission denied errors. Before running docker build the file has all rwx permissions, and I've checked inside the container that the file has rwx permissions.

Heres the execution code..
CMD chmod +x ./run.sh
CMD ./run.sh

The shebang is as follows..
#!/bin/sh

Error is..
/bin/sh: 1: ./run.sh: Permission denied

I've tried many stackoverflow solutions without any luck.. changing the shebang, changing CMD to ENTRYPOINT, modifying other code within my Dockerfile and run.sh. I don't understand why I get permission denied when any user has the ability to run the file.. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you want that first `CMD` to be a `RUN`. You can only have a single `CMD`, which defines what the container does at startup. `RUN` commands run during the build process and can make persistent changes to the filesystem.

Comment: During troubleshooting I've changed it to be a RUN command but didn't have any luck. I should have probably listed that I've done that but theres been so much troubleshooting its hard to list em out.

Comment: Still, the key point is that you *cannot* have multiple `CMD` statements. If you want to post a reproducible example, we can probably help you figure it out.

Comment: The issue was related to the volume not being exposed. Adding :z to the volume being used fixed it.